# How can I account for a decimal using the modulus operator

Tags: c++

The project I am working on needs to find some way of verifying that a variable after the modulus operation is either `number != 0`, `number > 0`, or `number < (0 < x < 1)`. I have the first two understood, however employing the mod operator to accomplish the third is difficult.

Essentially what I am looking to do is to be able to catch a value similar to something like this:

a) `2 % 6`

b) flag it and store the fact that .333 is less than 1 in a variable (bool)

c) perform a follow up action on the basis that the variable returned a value less than 1.

I have a feeling that the mod operator cannot perform this by itself. I'm looking for a way to utilize its ability to find remainders in order to produce a result.

edit: Here is some context. Obveously the below code will not give me what I want.

```
  if (((inGameTotalCoins-1) % (maxPerTurn+1)) < 0){
                            computerTakenCoins = (inGameTotalCoins - 1);
                            inGameTotalCoins = 1;
```

Comment: **`2 % 6`**, **`flag it and store the fact that .333 is less than 1 in a variable (bool)`**. It looks like you want division, but not modulo.

Comment: Why can't you `bool greaterThanOne = ((2 % 6) > 0);`?

Comment: What I'm asking is how do I detect that the output of the modulus operator is less than 1 and greater than 0?

Comment: There is an fmod function for doing modulo on floating point numbers.  You could get a result between 0 and 1 if you used fmod.  Note that in C/C++/C#  fmod and % only works correctly for positive numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotient is 0(2/6) with the fractional part discarded.The fractional part is .3333 ... So you are basically talking about the fractional part of the quotient , not the modulus value. Modulus can be calculated as follows :

```
(a / b) * b + (a % b) = a
(2 / 6) * 6 + (2 % 6) = 2
0 * 6 + (2 % 7) = 2
(2 % 6) = 2
```

*6 goes into 2 zero times with 2 left over.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:-

```
int number1 = 2;
int number2 = 6;
float number3 = static_cast<float>(number1) / static_cast<float>(number2);
bool isfraction = number3 > 0 && number3 < 1;
if(isfraction){
    std :: cout << "true\n" << number3;  
}
else{
    std :: cout << "false" << number3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`number != 0` includes `number > 0` and `number < (0 x < 1)`. And `number > 0` includes `number < (0 x < 1)`. Generally we do not classify so. For example, people classify `number > 0`, `number == 0` and `number < 0`.
If you do the modulous operation, you get remainder. Remainder's definition is not one thing. You can see it at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder